# Filtro dinámico personalizado

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intentando hacer un **filtro** personalizado para obtener los nombres de un listado, a través de un *input* busco el nombre que quiera. La conexión entre el *input* y la lista está hecha por medio de un *ngModel*.

El problema que se me presenta es cuando realizo una búsqueda y me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta la imagen, no reconoce *toLowerCase* como una función.

**users.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="users" class="container size-l">
  <div class="row margin-20">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input #userName class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="add(userName.value); userName.value=''">Agregar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Buscar usuario" class="form-control text-center">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div *ngIf="users" class="center margin-20">
  <div class="size-l text-center">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Id</th>
          <th scope="col">User</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users | filter : searchText : 'name'">
          <th><a routerLink="/posts/{{ user.id }}">{{ user.id }}</a></th>
          <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
      return items;
    }

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter( it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada uno de los `it` dentro del filter, es un objeto, asi que tendrias que acceder a una de sus propiedades para poder hacer un `toLowerCase()`

```
 return items.filter( it => {
          return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
        });
```

Podria ser :

```
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.propiedad.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
```

Comment: La has clavado, era eso lo que me faltaba. Gracias por la rápida respuesta.

Comment: @Rawsky Si te ha solucionado, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta. Gracias

Comment: Lo sé, me pide unos minutos mínimos antes de poder hacerlo.